# Add eventListener to http.Server before calling createServer?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to add an eventListener to `http.Server` (or `app` returned from `express()`) for the ’request’ event *before* calling `createServer`? Maybe its prototype?

I'm trying to add hooks for measuring response times without putting functions everywhere.

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/response-time .. easier to use a module then messing with protoype .

Comment: Good tip! but that module starts the timer after express runs two of its own first. I am trying to find a way to start on the servers request event.